# Enabling statistics in rqt_graph for ROS2

Tags: ros, rqt-graph, ros-crystal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ROS2 Crystal Clemmys in Ubuntu 18.04, and am successfully running rqt_graph gui on screen by using the command `rqt_graph --force-discover` (I had to use `--force-discover` as `qt_gui_main() found no plugin matching "rqt_graph.ros_graph.RosGraph"`)

I would like to enable statistics on my graph, so that I can observe the publish frequency (in Hz) and the average age of message (in ms). In ROS1 the command is `rosparam set enable_statistics true`, as shown in the tutorial for rqt_graph [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_graph).

However, I am not sure what the command is for ROS2. I tried this:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ ros2 param set enable_statistics true
usage: ros2 param set [-h] [--spin-time SPIN_TIME] [--include-hidden-nodes]
                  node_name name value
ros2 param set: error: the following arguments are required: value
```

It couldn't find the parameter enable_statistics. So I went to find out the actual name of the parameter by:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ ros2 param list
./rqt_gui_py_node_11381:
```

There were no parameters for enabling statistics at all.

May I know the proper way of enabling statistics for rqt_graph in ROS2?

Edit:  I think I keyed in another correct command:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ ros2 param set /rqt_gui_py_node_11381 /enable_statistics true
Set parameter successful
```

While the parameter has been found, still no statistics show up on the rqt_graph, even after I clicked on the refresh button.

How can I make the statistics appear, like in the picture in [the tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_graph)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324293/enabling-statistics-in-rqt_graph-for-ros2/) by [wan_da](https://answers.ros.org/users/41699/wan_da/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2019-05-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The statistics feature in `rqt_graph` depends on support for this in the `roscpp` and `rospy` client libraries.

I'm not aware of that support having been ported to their ROS 2 equivalents (ie: `rclcpp` and `rclpy`).

As such, I don't believe you can use this feature in `rqt_graph` right now in ROS 2.

> How can I make the statistics appear, like in the picture in [the tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_graph)?

Please note: the tutorial you link to is on the ROS 1 wiki. Documentation on ROS 2 itself may be found [here](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/). Individual packages are also listed on that site ([here](https://index.ros.org/p/rqt_graph/github-ros-visualization-rqt_graph/#crystal) for `rqt_graph` fi), but the `crystal` version does not link to any readily available wiki or documentation.

In general: even though it may happen that ROS 2 packages and nodes have the same name as their ROS 1 counterparts, there is a good chance that they do not have feature parity (ie: not everything from ROS 1 will work in ROS 2).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wan_da](https://answers.ros.org/users/41699/wan_da/) on 2019-05-30**:
ok. thank you very much